# Spring MVC: path variable {studentId} not displaying correctly

Tags: url, spring-mvc, path-variables

This really confuses me. 
Instead of proper URL with the value of one path variable `{studentId}`:
"http://somedomain.com:8080/someWebApp/essays/main/student/25/activity/add" (where 25 is the value of path variable `{studentId}`)
I get this in my URL: 
"http://somedomain.com:8080/someWebApp/essays/main/student/%7BstudentId%7D/activity/add"

This is my controller method for displaying some testPage and it works fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{studentId}/activity/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getForm(@PathVariable Integer studentId, Model model) {

        StudentActivityDTO studentActivityDTO = new StudentActivityDTO();
        Student student = studentService.get(studentId);
        studentActivityDTO.setStudent(student);
        studentActivityDTO.getActivity().setEssayFlag("Essay");
        model.addAttribute("studentActivityDTO", studentActivityDTO);
        model.addAttribute("courseList", courseService.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("teacherList", teacherService.getAll());

        return "testPage";
    }
```

And this is post controller method where this problem happens:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{studentId}/activity/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postForm(@ModelAttribute("studentActivityDTO") StudentActivityDTO studentActivityDTO,
                            @PathVariable Integer studentId,
                            Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to add new activity to student");

        Activity activity = studentActivityDTO.getActivity();
        activityService.add(studentId, activity);

        return "success/addActivitySuccess";
    }
```

In the first case `@PathVariable` works fine, in the second case it gives this error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{studentId}"
```

Instead of some value of the `{studentId}` being in the URL, I get string "{studentId}".

Can someone please tell me why?

**Update**: This is the important part of the jsp page (it is a pretty big page):

```
<c:url var="studentUrl" value="/essays/main/student/{studentId}/activity/add" />
<form:form modelAttribute="studentActivityDTO" method="POST" action="${studentUrl}">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you generate that URL?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I start from this URL as entry point: http://somedomain.com:8080/someWebApp/essays/main/student/search and as I navigate through the app, when I click on submit button I get that bad URL with string {studentId} in it. Until I press that submit button everything works fine.

Comment: Since the problem is in post controller method, show us the JSP page where you send the form and how you create the form tag's action attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you wanted

```
<c:url var="studentUrl" value="/essays/main/student/${studentActivityDTO.student.id}/activity/add" />
```